# LAN / WAN issues when transferring large amounts of data

Tags: lan, vlan, wan

I'm having an issue when I copy data from a PC to my NAS at gigabit speeds. My Router is an Asus RT-68U

```
ROUTER --> Port 3 --> Printer
    |
    |
    | ---> Port 1 --> NetGear GS108PE Switch
                              |
                    VLAN10    | --> Port 1 --> NAS Synology (1000)
                    VLAN10    | --> Port 2 
                    VLAN1     | --> Port 3 --> PC (1000)
                    VLAN20    | --> Port 4 --> IP Handset (10/100)
                    VLAN20    | --> Port 5 --> IP Server
                    VLAN10    | --> Port 6 --> NAS Zyxel (1000) 
                    VLAN10    | --> Port 7 --> Link to Netgear FS116 --|
                    VLAN1     |---> Port 8 Link to Router              |
                                                                       |--> Ports 1 - 16 10/100 devices


VLAN-ID Port Members
1         1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
10        1 2 3       7 8
20            3 4 5     8
```

Devices in VLAN10 can talk to each other and the Internet, but not VLAN20

Devices in VLAN20 can talk to each other and the Internet, but not VLAN10

The PC in VLAN1 can talk to anything

The issue is when I copy GB's worth of data from the PC to the Synology NAS I get full gigabit speeds but all devices lose the internet.

I'm assuming this is due to the PC being in VLAN1 the same as the routes default VLAN and the large transfer is killing the router. I get a similar issue if my laptop via Wifi to the router attempts a large backup to the synology NAS.

Any way to over come this ? I though the GS108PE switch would only route the data from port 3 to port 1, so I'm confused as to how it's affecting the router.

The GS108PE doesn't have any QoS, Rate Limit or Broadcast Filtering configured.

I have tried using port based VLANS and have set the port assignment as above, but then I could ping devices across the VLANS so I'm not sure whats happened there.   I've also created a new VLAN 5 to replace VLAN 1 incase that was causing the issue.

Is there any way to do this ? as I'd like to be able to do large data transfers between local devices whilst using the internet.

Thanks

Comment: Your setup seems correct, but symptoms suggest your Netgear switch just doesn't have the processing power to handle full rate traffic and inter-vlan routing itself. Implementing QoS/rate limiting may alleviate the problem, or could actually make it worse if the switch is at 100% load already. I would try to take some load away from the switch, perhaps move the VLAN control to the router if it isn't already?

Comment: My router can handle the VLAN, but it's all CLI based.. so setup is not that easy.  I'll try emailing Netgear and see what they say..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the Netgear to use port based VLAN's appears to have worked.

It's been suggested the issue is the Asus doing inter VLAN routing so it's getting flooded when I do large data transfers.

Setup port VLAN's and had no issues so far.

Comment: That ASUS model has not enough throughput to process that much data, so your data should be moved at layer 2 (switch level) not layer 3 (router level). VLAN routing is layer 3.

Comment: Also, ensure you have autonegotiation enabled for gigabit ethernet.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet#1000BASE-T  "Autonegotiation is a requirement for using 1000BASE-T ..."  If in your troubleshooting you disabled autonegotiation, turn it back on.